# Autokey setup.py script fails to recognize setuptools

Tags: scripts, python, autokey

I'm trying to install AutoKey so that I can use multiple keyboards for various macros.  I have downloaded the zip file from the github page, and have extracted the contained folder.

I tried to install it by running the included `septuplico` script with `python3 setup.py install`, but this resulted in the following error:

```
AutoKey needs setuptools in order to build.  Install it with your package manager 
(python-setuptools) or via pip (pip install setuptools)
```

Worried that setuptools wasn't installed, I ran `pip3 install setuptools`, which said that it was installed.  I ran the `setup.py` script again, but it still said the same error.  I tried again, this time having tried installing with `apt`, but this still delivered the error!

How am I able get rid of this error message and successfully install AutoKey?

Comment: Look at the script, and figure out how it detects `setuptools`.

Comment: @waltinator: It uses a try-catch statement to try to import `setuptools` into the program, and prints the error message if it recieves an import error.